# Tensorflow Installation Confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm

When I try to install TensorFlow using pip in the terminal (I'm on Mac), it says that I have it downloaded. The problem is when I try to use import tensorflow in pycharm it says that I do not have it installed. Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting? What did you name your `*.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

Check your project interpreter on PyCharm. Based on your description, it seems like you might have installed TensorFlow on your base. If PyCharm's interpreter is using a different environment (that is not your base environment) to run Python, you will not be able to access TensorFlow. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) allows users to configure environments and interpreters very easily.

I recommend that you use a virtual environment for your projects, since it allows you to manage different modules and installations more conveniently. For more information on Python virtual environments, refer to this [post](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

If anything is unclear, I'd be happy to elaborate.

Comment: How do I  change my pycharm interpreter to the base?

Comment: @KylenWilliams I'm basing my description off of the screenshots on this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html). Under the "Add Python Interpreter" menu, choose "System Interpreter" instead of "Virtualenv Environment" on the top. You should be able to configure from there.